# Graph Reset Query

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

To whomever,

I am having a graphing problem where it seems that previous data is being stacked on top of new data. I wanted to find a way to separate these so that I can get individual graphs per data set.

Briefly before we get into the script let me tell you what you're looking at. I have 8 data sets each one named somethingsomethingsomething...n=0,1,...,7. So there 8 different files with different sets of values for the wavelength (here I named it WL) and stokes parameters (here I named them SI SQ SU SV). I was told to make some graphs of them so here we are.

The following is what I have:

**the base**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants as c
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import re
```

**something to tell the program to not worry about random spaces in data set files**

```
split_on_spaces = re.compile(" +").split
```

**defining the arrays**

```
WL = np.array([])
SI = np.array([])
SQ = np.array([])
SU = np.array([])
SV = np.array([])
```

**code for data interpretation**

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Schmidt\\Desktop\\Python\\Homework_4\\CoolStuffLivesHere\\stokes_profiles_1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data=split_on_spaces(line.strip())
        if len(data) == 0:
            continue
        if len(data) != 5:
            sys.stderr.write("BAD LINE: {}".format(repr(line)))
            continue
        WL = np.append(WL, float(data[0]))
        SI = np.append(SI, data[1])
        SQ = np.append(SQ, data[2])
        SU = np.append(SU, data[3])
        SV = np.append(SV, data[4])
```

**plotting sequence**

```
plt.plot(WL,SI)
plt.show()
```

Then rinse and repeat for the other 3 parameters and then rinse and repeat for the other data sets as well. It works real fine for the first rendering. However for subsequent graphs it looks more like these: [first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxjXU.png), [second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Zvm.png).

So in a nut shell what line of code should I be typing in where to resolve my graph stacking issue?

Comment: plt.close() - it's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: where do I put it? at the end of it each plot line? once per data set?

Comment: before the next time you want to plot something without using the same plot. Otherwise, you're just adding to the existing plot.

Comment: I'm not catching your drift, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into subplots, you're just adding to the original plot. You need to close it if you want to re-use it.

i.e.

```
plt.plot(WL,SI)
plt.show()
plt.close()
plt.plot(WL,SQ)
```

Unless you want them on the same plot.